# Local Service Binding in Android - To use... or not to use?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

So I'm working with a local service and I'd like to have the activity send the service some commands. Besides just start and stop, I'd also like a pause, or restart command for the activity my service is performing (the commands aren't really that important here, just giving them as examples.

I think binding to a service would be the correct way to do this, but I'm unsure of two things.

1. The android docs say that unbinding from a service will kill it. What if I want my service to run in the background... then when my Activity onCreate()s I want to bind to the Service (to control it/send it commands) and onDestroy() I'd like to unbind the Activity from the service, but keep the Service running.
2. I'm having trouble understanding this excerpt from the Big Nerd Ranch book on Android development

> This pattern looks exciting. It is the only place in Android that
>   enables one Android component to directly talk to another. We do not
>   recommend it, though. Since services are effectively singletons, using
>   them this way provides no major benefits over just using a singleton
>   instead.

Is it essentially telling me that bind is an api that just makes things a little too complicated to really use for a Local Service?

Answer (score 4):

> The android docs say that unbinding from a service will kill it.

More accurately, when you call `unbindService()`, if there are no other outstanding bindings, and nothing called `startService()` on the service to have it be running that way, the service will be destroyed.

> What if I want my service to run in the background... then when my Activity onCreate()s I want to bind to the Service (to control it/send it commands) and onDestroy() I'd like to unbind the Activity from the service, but keep the Service running.

You would have to use both `startService()` (to better control the duration of the service) and `bindService()` then. And, if all you're doing is sending commands, I'd skip `bindService()` outright and just send the commands via `startService()`.

> I'm having trouble understanding this excerpt from the Big Nerd Ranch book on Android development

The last quoted sentence is... odd.

> Is it essentially telling me that bind is an api that just makes things a little too complicated to really use for a Local Service?

That's a reasonable interpretation of the quoted passage.

Personally, I find binding to be a pain in various body parts, more than it's worth for local services. A *service* is important, as an indication to the OS that you are doing background work worth keeping your process around a bit longer. But I'll use the command pattern and event buses over local binding. The binding itself is state, state that needs to be managed with respect to configuration changes. Retained fragments make this easier than it used to be, but it's still aggravating.

The binding pattern more important for remote services, where the client and the service are in separate apps. While this introduces a whole host of new and exciting problems, there are only so many IPC options in Android, and remote services offer options that are difficult-to-impossible to implement using other IPC options.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd like to stay away from eventbus libs (for now), but setting up a LocalBroadcastReciever seems fine for Service -> Activity, but how would you recommend Activity -> Service commands? Via just startService() again?

Comment: @EGHDK: "but setting up a LocalBroadcastReciever seems fine for Service" -- if what you want works with `Intent` structures, and you want the results always delivered on the main application thread, `LocalBroadcastManager` is fine. "how would you recommend Activity -> Service commands? Via just startService() again?" -- sure.

Comment: Two more things! 1. Just to be sure you're saying startService() with another Intent extra as the command right? Because then onCreate won't get called, but onStartCommand will get called, and I can essentially use it as a router method. 2. "nothing called startService() on the service to have it be running that way" Wait so I know I can just log this, but even reading through the docs, I thought onBind will still call onStartCommand()

Comment: @EGHDK: 1. Correct. 2. No, AFAIK `onStartCommand()` is only triggered by `startService()`, not `bindService()`. I have never used both systems in the same app, though, so it's possible that I am mistaken.

Comment: Hmm... just a note. They way that AS handles an intent service template is pretty cool. Just has a static method to invoke all of the Service methods. Pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, unbinding from the service will destroy the service, unless it was started first. So if you start the service and then bind to it, it will survive your activity recreation (make sure that you stop the service at some point with `stopSelf()`. This is mentioned in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) about bound services.
2. Not sure what their problem is with it, yes, the service is effectively a singleton. They might have a problem with the service being to tightly coupled to the activity, but the service doesn't have to know about the activity, you can also send data back with a (local) broadcastmanager and register a receiver for it in your activity.

Comment: I understand that Service -> Activity with a LocalBroadcast would work. How would I send a command from Activity -> Service?

Comment: The activity can have a reference to the service instance, so you can call methods on it from activity. See the code samples in the docs link above. If you bind to the service it returns a binder object. Use this to get a reference to your service, then you can call public methods in the service.